# Ignoring libraries when setting exception breakpoints in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, exception, breakpoints

I often use exception breakpoints when debugging in Eclipse.  The problem I often have is my framework libraries (especially Tomcat) often throw exceptions as part of their normal lifecycle.

If I set an ArrayIndexOutOfBounds exception for example, then I hit the breakpoint several times in sun.reflect.generics.parser.SignatureParser during startup.

Is it possible to get eclipse to filter out exceptions thrown from certain packages?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can filter the places where the breakpoint should hit in the breakpoint properties dialog.

Right click the breakpoint -> Breakpoint properties -> Filtering

and you can specify the locations as shown below.

[image]

More information [here](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/tasks/tasks-create-exception-filter-expression.htm).